# What's more efficient in python - comparing lists, or strings?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there any difference between checking whether `['a','b','c'] == ['a','b','c']` and `'abc' =='abc'` ?

I don't expect there to be, but wanted to double check.

Comment: why would you be concerned about this ... any difference is likely to be trivial ... the string compare is likely a little faster... but seriously why does it matter? (I mean are you running into slowdowns that are affecting your programs execution?)

Comment: Strings - because it's a "primitive" operation (that is, while both can be viewed as comparing sequences, the string benefits from an intrinsic function). But use the most appropriate structure.

Comment: Why haven't you measured it yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is a time test that uses [`timeit.timeit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#timeit.timeit) to compare the speeds of the two methods:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> list1 = ['a','b','c']
>>> list2 = ['x','y','z']
>>> timeit("list1 == list2", "from __main__ import list1, list2")
0.31944255484984296
>>> str1 = "abc"
>>> str2 = "xyz"
>>> timeit("str1 == str2", "from __main__ import str1, str2")
0.2439259738318924
>>>
```

As you can see, comparing two strings is somewhat faster than comparing two lists.  For the reason why, see @user2864740's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21396414/whats-more-efficient-in-python-comparing-lists-or-strings/21396449#comment32273606_21396414). :)

Comment: Thank you, iCodez and user2864740. Will accept this answer once the time limit passes

Comment: One problem with the test, though: it's possible (likely) that `str1` and `str2` refer to the same interned `str` object, so an equality test would be very fast: any object should compare equal to itself.

Comment: @chepner - I changed the value of `str2` to compensate.

Comment: @chepner: that would require a special test in the string compare routine for that (relatively) rare situation. I suspect python does not bother with that test.

Comment: When comparing larger strings the difference is huge. With `s = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'* 18000` I measure 58.8ns to compare with itself and 1.29ms to compare two lists of the same content... a difference of 22000x!

Comment: @iCodez Nice. I noticed that it remained faster with different strings, too. I don't think the result was in question; it's just good to have a test that removes the possibility of identical objects skewing the results.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the string advantage increases as the sequences grow larger:

```
from timeit import timeit

for p in range(4):
    N = 10 ** p
    list1 = list(range(10)) * N
    list2 = list(list1)
    list2[-1] = 0
    str1 = ''.join(map(str, list1))
    str2 = ''.join(map(str, list2))

    # Sequences are equal except for their last element.
    # And everything is the same length.
    assert list1[:-1] == list2[:-1]
    assert str1[:-1]  == str2[:-1]
    assert list1      != list2
    assert str1       != str2
    assert len(list1) == len(list2)
    assert len(str1)  == len(str2)
    assert len(list1) == len(str1)

    a = timeit("list1 == list2", "from __main__ import list1, list2")
    b = timeit("str1 == str2", "from __main__ import str1, str2")
    print 'Length:', N * 10
    print '  list:  ', a
    print '  str:   ', b
    print '  ratio: ', a / b
```

Some results:

```
Length: 10
  list:   0.0885802666801
  str:    0.0493016279308
  ratio:  1.79670064454
Length: 100
  list:   0.33228903865
  str:    0.0540730467332
  ratio:  6.14518801372
Length: 1000
  list:   2.78192754261
  str:    0.122594386356
  ratio:  22.6921282882
Length: 10000
  list:   26.8981546711
  str:    0.78435279802
  ratio:  34.2934387931
```

Comment: Very impressive :) Thank you! Bookmarking code if I need to test more things.